# How to create a folder and sub folder

Tags: livecode

How to create folder using live code. I am using linux operating system my current Directory is

```
"/home/user1/myproject/"
```

I want to create folder inside myproject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create folder pathName` should work fine